# CakePHP default layout for xlsx

Tags: cakephp

I have a method which exports riport data into an xlsx file in my CakePHP 2 project. It is working well. In the same time it seems it just ignores anything what I put into View/Layouts/xlsx/default.ctp

In my routes.php I have

```
Router::parseExtensions('json', 'xlsx');
```

In my controller I have

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

My View/Riports/xlsx/export.ctp is rendered, but View/Layouts/xlsx/default.ctp is ignored.

What do I miss?

Comment: Do you wanna create a diffent theme for xlsx or just a layout?

Comment: Just a layout where I can set debug to 0, change cache behaviour, etc.

Comment: Probably best to perform those things in a callback, like `beforeRender()` you can move that code to a Component if you want to separate if from your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're out of luck here. From the documentation;

*The data view classes don’t support layouts. They assume that the view file will output the serialized content.*

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-a-data-view-with-view-files

But I may be wrong of course :)

Comment: Than I should add the same few lines of code to my view files. Thanks.

Comment: Or use the suggestion I put below your question; inside a callback or a component. You can check what kind of extension is requested and act on that